# import android.provider.AlarmClock not working Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been searching many videos about creating Intents for alarms, and all of them use the class AlarmClock from "android.provider.AlarmClock". However, if I try to import the class and use it, It does't appear in the "Auto-complete"... Am I missing any implementation in the build.graddle or It just doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: What happens if you just add the import statement directly?

Comment: Nothing, it just stays gray and can't really use it... It doesn't work in the auto-complete neither writing it myself

Comment: If it is just gray, not being under lined by red, means it is okay, no issue. Probably you should try importing the library by pasting it, then clean build and then start calling the methods,